# keyup() validation not working properly with jquery-ui dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have jquery-ui dialog has some inputs fields for update user information.
whenever the user type into one of these fields (**using `keyup()`**), the value of the input will be sent to database to check weather that name exist in the data base or not. **Unfortunatelly, it always return that there is no such a name in database** (even if it actually exist).

**Notice:** the form of "update user information" is included to `index.php` (main page). I tried to make a new project with that form as main page, and it works properly. So I'm thinking there is problem with including the form page in its main page. Is that right?!!

the **form** that included to main page:

```
<div id="container">
          <form action="" class="fixed-dialog" id="customForm" dir="ltr">
                <table> 
                 <tr>
                  <td id="label-td"><label for="name">firstName</label></td>
                  <td id="input-td">
                  <input type="text" class="form-group" id="firstName" name="name" />
                  </td>
                  <td id="span-td">
                  <span id="firstNameInfo">first Name</span>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                   </table>
            <div>
                <input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Update">
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript file:** that includes jquery-ui dialog and validating the input field:

```
var form       = $("#customForm");
var name       = $("#firstName");
var nameInfo   = $("#firstNameInfo");
var state      = false;


name.keyup(validateName);

function validateName(){
    if(name.val().length < 2){
        name.removeClass("valid");
        nameInfo.removeClass("valid");
        name.addClass("error");
        nameInfo.addClass("error");
        nameInfo.text("More than Two Letters!!");
        state = false;
    }else{
        if(name.val().length >= 2){
            var username = name.val();
            //here, getting validate.php page, which takes the value of the input and check it with DB
            $.post('includes/validate.php',{names:username}, function(data){
                if(data != 0){
                    //if there is a match with DB.
                    name.removeClass("valid");
                    nameInfo.removeClass("valid");
                    name.addClass("error");
                    nameInfo.addClass("error");
                    nameInfo.text("it's already there..");
                    state = false;
                }else{
                    //if there is no match with DB.
                    name.removeClass("error");
                    nameInfo.removeClass("error");
                    name.addClass("valid");
                    nameInfo.addClass("valid");
                    nameInfo.text("Accepted!!");
                    state = true;
                }
            });

        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

the last file is **validate.php**, which will check for the input value in the DB:

```
include "includes/config.php";
include "./functions.php";
$name = &$_POST['names'];
if($name != ""){
    arabicQuerySetUp();
    $query_search_name = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_first_name = '{$name}' ";
    $query_search_name_result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_search_name);
    $count_names = mysqli_num_rows($query_search_name_result);
    if($count_names != 0){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned above, I tried to make it in new project, and not included it to the main page; and it's worked fine.

I tried too much to find where the error is in my code, but I couldn't. So I came here looking for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Never ever trust user inputs...

Comment: Have you checked your log files to see if you get any errors?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson,  I forgot to use escape(). Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: You should use Prepared Statements instead of escaping the data. Escaping will never truly protect you (not even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is 100% safe).

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, I'm not seeing any errors in consol. What do you mean by log files?!!

Comment: Check your web servers log files....

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , Thanks man it worked, **web server log files** helped me to find the error and fix it. Now it works as it should be. Thanks again!!